# Issues with retrieving data from webrequest using xamarin forms

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

i've been strugling with this "thing" for the pass 2 weeks now

```
 public class Post
 {
     public int userId { get; set; }
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }
     public string body { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage    
 {
     private const string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
     private HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();
     private ObservableCollection<Post> _post;

     public MainPage()      
     {
      InitializeComponent();        
     }

     protected override async void OnAppearing()
     {
         try
         {
             var content = await _Client.GetStringAsync(url);

             var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(content);
             _post = new ObservableCollection<Post>(post);
             Post_List.ItemsSource = _post;

             await DisplayAlert("content", content, "ok");
            base.OnAppearing();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Debug.WriteLine(ex);
         }
     }
 }
```

with this code everithing is returned in xamarin forms / windows
but in android it doesnt return anything, and the only error is 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Please send some help!
Thanks

Comment: do you have internet permissions enabled in Android?  And have you looked at the InnerException to get the details on what is causing the exception?

Comment: Yes i have permissions, and in android is breakig in 

"var content = await _Client.GetStringAsync(url);"

and in the exceptions tab does not specify the problem... @Jason

Comment: you need to look at the InnerException property of the Exception object

Comment: Where is the InnerException property? @Jason
here i have the code of trace(stack) used with a try catch
https://www.pastiebin.com/5af5a14bcbbe1

Comment: On the Exception object.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jglxc2 @Jason

Comment: drill down into the InnerException object and see if it tells you anything more meaningful

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jgm130 @Jason

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jgm3fn @Jason

Comment: That seems like a meaningful error message.  Have you tried googling it?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems there is an issue with the server certificate. Fortunately, an app can accept any certificate using a custom validator.

> An application can set the ServerCertificateValidationCallback
>   property to a method to use for custom validation by the client of the
>   server certificate.

Certificate validator implemementation:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

For more information [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback).